# advanced user/staff online activity tracking?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, tracking

I have been looking for a solution to tracking the staff in our website administration area.  I would like be able to reliably see how long each staff member spends online (working) each day, week, month, etc..  There are a couple ways to go about this but I haven't been able to find a good solution.

- Log each page load to a database with a timestamp and url/filename/page

*The issue with this method is how do you really know if the user was 'active' on that page.  If there is 30 minutes between page loads you don't know if they loaded the page, spent 2 mins looking at it and then the next 28 minutes playing Xbox.*

- Use javascript to log on page load and on page unload

*This method would be slightly better than the previous method because you should know if they close the browser and you can end the 'session' right there.  However it still has big problems like the first one.  If they leave the page open and step away from the computer.*

I know there will never be a 100% reliable method for tracking this, especially if staff is purposely trying to fool the system.   I am, however, trying to get the most reliable tracking I possibly can under these circumstances.

I think a method using ajax that tracks mouse activity would be the best.  If the mouse activity stops for X minutes then you can decide that the user is no longer there.  Essentially you would need to track that and then add up all of the time that the mouse spent active while on the site.

Does anyone have any suggestions for already made scripts that can do this? 
Or advice if I were to build my own solution?

Comment: I'm thinking of a particular *Simpson's* episode ...

Comment: I hope you're telling your staff what you're up to... The second method will *work* but expect it to result in a slowdown of the site for a user and also a huge increase in traffic to your server. Neither of which is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can send periodically an heartbeat to your backend via AJAX. 
Also you can log the users actions with javascript.
You could define some rules which are sent together with the heartbeat.

Example:

Javascript AJAX Heartbeat every 10 Seconds with the following data:

```
data: {
    lastAction: { type: 'userMouseMoved', timestamp: 12312312313 }
}
```